# Resizing an image from the network in android?

Tags: android, image, download, resize

I'm trying to adapt the code in google developer guides to resize a large image obtained from HTTP.
In order to resize the image, I have to process it once (using Bitmapfactory.decodeStream) to determine its original height and width. Then, I have to run Bitmapfactory.decodeStream again in order to resize it. THe problem with this approach is that I cannot use the same stream twice. 
If I do, the second called to decodeStream returns null.

I thought about trying to clone / copy the stream first so that I would have two copies to work with. However, this uses up memory, which was the problem I was trying to solve by resize the image, in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `Bitmap` returned by `Bitmapfactory.decodeStream()` for the resize operation. You do not need to decode it twice. You have it already.

```
Bitmap b = Bitmapfactory.decodeStream(/* your InputStream */);
// get original dimensions from b
int h = b.getHeight();
int w = b.getWidth();
// resize b to half (actually quarter) size
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, w/2, h/2, false);
```

Comment: could you please share some code?
I need to called decodeStream() for the first time to get the original dimensions of the image. 
Then I need to call it again to actually sub-sample the image. 
..at least that's what I understood from the documentation. 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
(see decodeSamplefromResource() method)

Comment: thanks. 
Doesn't this approach still load the whole image (at it's original resolution) into memory?

Comment: It does, but decoding the `InputStream` does it anyway. If you recycle the original `Bitmap b`, you should be fine.